How is the advertising time of one channel set within the advertising interval?
I am writing a project for BLE based on the TI CC2652P7 microcontroller and I cannot fully understand how to set up advertising broadcasting. On the Internet, you can often find posts and images that show that we can set up the advertising interval and the channels on which the advertising will be (for ease of understanding, let's assume that we use all three channels: 37, 38, 39).
So, let's say I set the advertising interval to 1 second. How is this time divided between the three channels? Approximately into three equal parts? Because, you can often see in images on the Internet that there are indications of a duration of no more than 10 ms.
As a result, I get two different understandings of advertising.
Either one advertising interval is divided approximately into three equal parts
Or up to 10 ms of broadcasting within one interval is allocated to each channel, and the rest of the time the device does nothing on the air?
enter image description here

The time is not divided.  Each channel has its own frequency, so they can be sent simultaneously.

Typically every bluetooth chip on the market only has one radio/antenna which can only be tuned to one frequency at a time. In this case it's not possible to send the packets simultaneously.

Have you read anywhere online that the 1 second can be divided into three equally sized parts? This is totally wrong.
The image you posted is correct. The standard says:
"The time between the beginning of two consecutive ADV_IND PDUs within an advertising event shall be less than or equal to 10 ms. The advertising event shall be closed within the advertising interval."

does this mean that if I set the interval to 1 second, then out of 1000ms I will only broadcast up to 30ms (up to 10ms for each channel, of which there are only 3)?

That is correct.

Then I don't really understand the meaning of this. Why broadcast only 30ms out of 1000 (that's only 3%!)?

For example to save energy consumption. Use a shorter advertising interval if you want to.
